# Remotely launching applications with access to network shares

Tags: windows-7, automation

I use PsExec to launch an application remotely, but it does not have access to the network shares.

Basically we're talking about my old machine, which now serves as an HTPC. This is hard if it does not get access to the media drives. The app launched is the player obviously.

Ed: This seems to be quite the obscure problem. Apart from answering I guess another option is pointing me to a community that has the necessary know-how.

Comment: When your "remote" application runs, does it rely on existing network shares as a prerequisite? If so, you need to automate the mounting of the network shares before running the application... Your question doesn't give us any information to go on so can you update your question with any important information as to what your app requires to work, for example. Does your app require any configuration when it runs so it knows how to connect to the required shares?

Comment: Let me try to be verbose then. The app(VLC Player) is local ofc. The media that it plays reside on the shares. They are permanent shares and are readily accessible when booting into windows. One option is to turn on the machine and manually double-click the app icon, in which case all is fine. But when the app is launched remotely the shares are not visible to it. In fact, when I specifically use the app interface to browse for files the shares show up as a red X. Though only initially, clicking on them opens them without further issue. But again, this is only manually via the app interface.

Comment: Although this may seem similar to PsExec, you can run an "on demand" scheduled task using the following syntax: `schtasks /run /s <machine name> /tn <task name>` - so (in theory), create a task on the remote computer (for simplicity), use the command I've just written to call the scheduled task...?

Comment: I'm gonna try it later and report. Seems it could be a viable workaround.